# Monitor 2 threads in java, which are dependent on each other based on timing using java.util.Timer

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, telnet

I wanted to know how I can monitor two threads, in such a way that if one thread is in waiting state for a particular time, I would want to run another thread...

To be particular in what I'm doing. I've 2 threads.. Writer Thread :

```
writer = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      Util.copyStream(remoteInput, localOutput);
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
};

writer.setPriority(Thread.currentThread().getPriority() + 1);
writer.start();
reader.setDaemon(true);
reader.start();

try {
  writer.join();
  reader.interrupt();
} catch(InterruptedException e) {

}
```

and the reader thread :

```
reader = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    int ch;
    try {
        while(!interrupted() && (ch = localInput.read()) != -1) {
          System.out.print((char)ch);
          localOutput.write(ch);
          if (ch==10) {
              remoteOutput.write(ch);
              remoteOutput.flush();
              sleep(1000);
              continue;
          }
          remoteOutput.write(ch);
            remoteOutput.flush();
          }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
};
```

So, if my writer thread is not writing from "remoteInput" to "localOutput" for more than a particular time for example 3 secs, I should be "run"ing the reader thread.. ,so that reader reads from "localInput" and writing to "remoteOutput".
localInput and remoteInput are **InputStreams**, whereas, remoteInput and remoteOutput are simple **OutputStreams**. I also wanted to know if it's possible to do this using **java.util.Timer** 
Please help me through..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reformat please your code properly first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of wait/notify along with Timer class to decide when to trigger notify  events.